# SharePoint Online (Office 365): REST API is not working from yesterday (19th September 2019)

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, lookup-column, error, cumulative-update

Since from yesterday 19th September 2019, Simple Rest URL `Select=*` is not working.

**Note:** list is having 12 person or group/lookup column excluding created by  & modified by.

However it was working fine before.

**Error:**

> The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup column it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by administrator.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: @Tally also facing the same error as mentioned - [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269676/too-many-lookup-columns-error-message-despite-stable-list-being-in-use-and-n). Maybe because of any updates by microsoft.

Comment: Indeed, I have the same issue, yesterday it was still working (I'm in the UK, so GMT).

Comment: Yep has the same issue, briefly, then it went back to expected. Must have been an update that was then rolled back